# Xcode 7 Organizer loading taking forever - How to fix?

Tags: ios, xcode, submit, xcode7

After Xcode 7 update, organizer takes forever to load and I was unable to submit iOS 9 app. Is there a way to disable automatic iOS Apps refresh, or another way to fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Also deleting the content of:

> /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products

will help loading faster

Comment: This did it for me. I had 100s of products in that directory.

Comment: Did this, but the Products just come back after Xcode is reopened.

Comment: Yes, you should clean them if the Xcode freezes and then force restart Xcode

Comment: As me, I've deleted them, but when I open organizer, it still so slow for loading. And each time I archived a new app, it also take long time to load the archive and UI even if I just got no file before.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted about 2 years worth of archives and now Organizer loads quickly. Right-click and show in finder and just select all. xcode delete archive is extremely slow.

Answer (score 0):

If the Xcode organizer is taking way too long to display it is because you have tons of archived apps.    The best thing to do is clear out old archives and leave newer archives for apps recently submitted to app store as you will need symbol details for exceptions.    see http://blog.favo.org/post/31649090293/xcode-5-places-to-save-some-disk-space